# Connect to Foxpro with PHP using OLE DB driver

Tags: php, odbc, adodb, foxpro

I'm trying to connect to a Foxpro database using the OLE DB Driver

I downloaded the driver from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839 and installed it then create a php script

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$conn->Open("Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=C:\Opera3\Comp_I.DBC;Collating Sequence=machine");
```

This gives me the following error

> `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> ADODB.Connection<br/><b>Description:</b> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test1.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test1.php(4): com->Open('Provider=vfpole...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test1.php on line 4`

Any help in getting this working would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a 64 bit installation?

Comment: Hint: Create a DSN first within the OLEDB/ODBC settings. You can test it there. Then copy & paste the string over into your PHP script.

Comment: Yes it is a 64bit installation

Comment: How do I get to OLEDB/ODBC Settings? - do you mean the ODBC Data Source Administrator?

Comment: I now have this working - uninstalled and reinstalled from command line as administrator for all users  and now it works

Comment: @mjsolo - You should post the solution as an answer, so it is easier for others to find.

Answer (score -1):

As requested

uninstalled and reinstalled from command line as administrator for all users and now it works –

Comment: please explain with some detail information. Thank you.